# Add submenu to existing menu

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a basic menu for which I would like to add a submenu, that appears only when a certain menu link is hovered. Everything I have tried does not hide the submenu when a link is not hovered. Here is my code:

CSS

```
.navmenu{
float:right;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight:400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navmenu li{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.navmenu li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#eee;
padding:15px 37px 19px 37px;
}

.navmenu li a:hover{
background:#36332e;
}

.active  a{
background:#36332e;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="navmenu">
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubLink 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: would you like to use a jquery plugin to do that? or you just want to do it from scratch?

Comment: boostrap has a really nice ui and has support for what you want to do. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns has some information on this subject. I have used it myself it works.

Comment: @KevinCittadini I dont want to use jquery. I want to keep my existing menu and incorporate a drop down sub menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initially hide the menu:

```
.navmenu li ul { display: none; }
```

and then display it when you hover over the nav item:

```
.navmenu li:hover ul { display: none; }
```

You should also be careful about defining styles that target `.navmenu li` or `.navmenu li a` because those will also target your submenu. You should instead use [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), giving you more control over the non-submenu links, so your selectors will look like:

```
.navmenu > li
.navmenu > li > a
```

I've encorperated some of those changes into this JSFiddle to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/B5P26/

Edit:

This is actually going to lose it's hover state when you hover over the submenu links:

```
.navmenu > li > a:hover {
  background:#36332e;
}
```

Instead, you should do this:

```
.navmenu ul { position: absolute; }
.navmenu > li:hover { background: #e6332e; }
.navmenu > li > a { display: block; }
```

Since the `<ul>` is nested inside the `<li>` element, you won't lose the hover state when you hover over the submenu links. I updated the fiddle to reflect these changes.

Comment: Thank you! Its a great starting point. I can style it however I want now that it works.

Comment: Just posted a quick update that takes care of some color issues that you might have when dealing with hovering over the submenu.

Comment: Quick question. I dont mean to bother you. I cant maintain the same styling for some reason. Would you be able to help me with this please?

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41738/continuation)

Answer (score -2):

```
<ul class="navmenu">
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Sub Link 1</a>

         <ul>
          </li> <a href=# >hi hi hi</a>
           <ul>
            <li>hello hello hello</li>
            <li>hello hello hello</li>
            <li>hello hello hello</li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          </li><a href=# >hi hi hi</a> </li>
          </li> <a href=# >hi hi hi</a> </li>
         </ul>

         </li>

        <li><a href="#">SubLink 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
</ul>
```